# Android: Logcat string for Bluetooth ON

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

My application will switch on Bluetooth. I want to wait till bluetooth is switched on.
I will look for string

```
 MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_CONNECTED=1
```

in logcat and then proceed.

I want to know if this method is correct or i should be looking for some other string. What is the best way to know whether i am looking for right string in logcat. Is there any collection/document to learn what all info can be gathered using logcat

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with below as logcat may prevent your app from responding. You should either run this piece of code or your own app in a seperate thread to keep it responsive.  Below code asks logcat to send logs to your app and you can do investigate the logs as you see fit.

```
private static final String SEARCH_STRING = "MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_CONNECTED=1";

  try {
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat");
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

      StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
      String line = "";
      boolean didFind = false;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null && !didFind) {
        log.append(line);
        didFind = line.toUpperCase().contains(SEARCH_STRING))
      }
  } 
catch (IOException e) {}
```

I hope it helps.